# What do excel xml cell attribute values mean?

Tags: xml, excel, cell

Looking at the xml of an excel spreadsheet, I see these cells under sheetData/row:

```
<c r="T1" s="23" t="s"><v>17</v></c>
<c r="AP1" s="98"><v>28</v></c>
```

By looking at the spreadsheet, I can see that the first cell is a string (which I can look up in the sharedStrings file), and I know that the second one is the value "28", from which I hypothesise that if a cell has the attribute `t="s"`, it is a string, otherwise it is a value. Is this correct?

I am guessing that the r, s, and t stand for 'row', 'style', and 'type', but can someone clarify for me what they mean and what the possible values for them are? E.g, I see some cells with the attribute t="str", is that the same as "s" or does it mean something special?

I couldn't find any documentation or specification for the excel xml files, so if such a thing exists it would be helpful to be pointed in it's direction.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

- `r` = Reference
- `s` = Style Index
- `t` = Cell Data Type

The documentation for the `Cell` class is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.cell.aspx)

The possible cell data types are:

- `b` - boolean
- `d` - date in ISO8601 format
- `e` - error
- `inlineStr` - string that doesn't use the shared string table
- `n` - number
- `s` - shared string
- `str` - formula string

These values are in section 18.18.11 of the ECMA-376 standard which can be found [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm) (specifically they are on pages 2442-2443 of the PDF file in the ECMA-376 4th edition part 1 download)

Looking at the XML schema later in that PDF file (page 3912, line 2301), the use of the `t` attribute is optional and the default value is `n` - i.e. a number

---

Part 1 of the 5th edition of the ECMA-476 spec was released in 2016. The equivalent page references for the 5th edition are: page 2451 for the documentation of ST_CellType and page 3928, line 2301 for the ST_CellType entry in the XML schema

Comment: How do you know which attributes are optional?

Comment: If you go to page 3912 of the ECMA-376 4th edition part 1 download PDF file and look at line 2301 it says: `<xsd:attribute name="t" type="ST_CellType" use="optional" default="n"/>` I'll add the page reference into the question and also add references to the 5th edition spec which came out in 2016

Comment: On a more general question of finding out which attributes are optional, it's just a question of looking at the XML Schema where attributes will be specified as either `use="required"` or `use="optional"` The Spreadsheet ML schema starts on page 3869 (4th edition) or page 3885 (5th edition)

Answer (score -1):

have a look at [Open XML SDK.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) Its a good starting point for what your looking for

Comment: I don't think that's what I'm looking for. I don't use windows, and don't want to have to trawl through the source code of their program to find the explanation.

Comment: Also, the link gives a 404