# OpenXML - Cell.DateType is null

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I can't determine when a Cell is a date.

[image: Date DataType Cell]

I noticed the DataType is null so I can't distinguish if it's a Number of a Date.

I am using the next code to extract the cells:

```
WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)workbookPart.GetPartById(worksheetId);
SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
Row[] rows = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Row>().ToArray();
for (int i = 0; i < rows.Length; i++)
{
    List<Cell> cells = rows[i].Elements<Cell>().ToList();
    foreach (var cell in cells) 
    {
        if (cell.DataType != null && cell.DataType.Value == CellValues.Date)
            //this line is not hit for some reason
         }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In short it is null because it is supposed to be for numeric and date types.

OpenXML documentation on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh298534.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> The value of the DataType property is null for numeric and date types.
> It contains the value CellValues.SharedString for strings, and
> CellValues.Boolean for Boolean values.

There is a way though to distinguish between date and number cell formats using the **NumberFormatId** on the **CellFormat**. The trick is finding what id maps to what format. You can find out what format to use by creating new excel file and set a cell to the format in question (i.e. date):

[image]

Then extract excel file using 7zip and look inside xl/styles.xml file:

[image]

In the image above you can see this formatId 14 translates to short date. For a complete list of formats please refer to [ECMA-376 documentation for Office Open XML formats](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm) (number format table should be buried somewhere inside <strike>part 4</strike>. They moved it to part 1 in section 18.8.30).

I created an enumeration for the most common formatIds:

```
private enum Formats
    {
        General = 0,
        Number = 1,
        Decimal = 2,
        Currency = 164,
        Accounting = 44,
        DateShort = 14,
        DateLong = 165,
        Time = 166,
        Percentage = 10,
        Fraction = 12,
        Scientific = 11,
        Text = 49
    }
```

You could then create a helper function that will get you the formatted value the way you would like:

```
private static string GetFormattedCellValue(WorkbookPart workbookPart, Cell cell)
    {
        if (cell == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        string value = "";
        if (cell.DataType == null) // number & dates
        {
            int styleIndex = (int)cell.StyleIndex.Value;
            CellFormat cellFormat = (CellFormat)workbookPart.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.CellFormats.ElementAt(styleIndex);
            uint formatId = cellFormat.NumberFormatId.Value;
            
            if (formatId == (uint)Formats.DateShort || formatId == (uint)Formats.DateLong)
            {
                double oaDate;
                if (double.TryParse(cell.InnerText, out oaDate))
                {
                    value = DateTime.FromOADate(oaDate).ToShortDateString();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                value = cell.InnerText;
            }
        }
        else // Shared string or boolean
        {
            switch (cell.DataType.Value)
            {
                case CellValues.SharedString:
                    SharedStringItem ssi = workbookPart.SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable.Elements<SharedStringItem>().ElementAt(int.Parse(cell.CellValue.InnerText));
                    value = ssi.Text.Text;
                    break;
                case CellValues.Boolean:
                    value = cell.CellValue.InnerText == "0" ? "false" : "true";
                    break;
                default:
                    value = cell.CellValue.InnerText;
                    break;
            }
        }

        return value;
    }
```

Comment: Do you know if different encoding types can be handled as well in open xml then how we can implement it?

Comment: regarding the styleIndex = (int)cell.StyleIndex.Value; part, StyleIndex can also be null, which causes an error when trying to access the Value property.  I just check first to see if StyleIndex is null, and if so then leave formatId as 0

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer states that the formats are documented in Part 4 but apparently they have been moved to Part 1. I found them by searching for `#,##0.00`. They are currently in 18.8.30 numFmt (Number Format) for the *number formats whose formatCode value is implied rather than explicitly saved in the file*. See *18.8.31 numFmts (Number Formats)* for *number formats in this workbook, consisting of a sequence of numFmt records, where
each numFmt record defines a particular number format, indicating how to format and render the numeric value of a cell*.

The following are the implied formatCode attribute for all languages.

```
ID formatCode
0 General
1 0
2 0.00
3 #,##0
4 #,##0.00
9 0%
10 0.00%
11 0.00E+00
12 # ?/?
13 # ??/??
14 mm-dd-yy
15 d-mmm-yy
16 d-mmm
17 mmm-yy
18 h:mm AM/PM
19 h:mm:ss AM/PM
20 h:mm
21 h:mm:ss
22 m/d/yy h:mm
37 #,##0 ;(#,##0)
38 #,##0 ;[Red](#,##0)
39 #,##0.00;(#,##0.00)
40 #,##0.00;[Red](#,##0.00)
45 mm:ss
46 [h]:mm:ss
47 mmss.0
48 ##0.0E+0
49 @
```

There are many other implied format codes that are language-dependent, such as:

```
28 [$-404]e"年"m"月"d"日" m"月"d"日"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `cell.HasValue` insteed? Because int and Datetime is not always nullable, it depends of how the code is written.