# Where is the XML in this Office Open XML example?

Tags: .net, excel, openxml, office-2010

I am looking into the various options of generating Office documents on a server, in particular Excel documents.

The site isn't important but what is relevant is that it used the MS open XML library listed below. I checked out the article on Open Office here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/97307/Using-C-and-Open-XML-SDK-2-0-for-Microsoft-Office

This project seems to set a reference to an openXML library

```
C:\Program Files\Open XML SDK\V2.0\lib\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll
```

that is part of the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Microsoft Office.

When I ran the project, the code produced a file that XLSX extension that appeared to be in binary format, not XML format. Similarly, I have seen other Open Office coding examples the file read was a binary format, instead of a file in XML format. For example, when I open up the file in Note, I see "unreadable" characters rather than tags.

Isn't the whole point of Open office XML to read and write XML documents that are in an open format?

Comment: This might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886027/xlsx-xml-format
I guess it's essentially a zip file.

Comment: Unzip them with 7zip, they're actually a whole folder hierarchy of XML files and other resources.

Comment: Instead of changing the extension to see the XML of the docx files, use the [Open XML Productivity Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=30425) that can be downloaded along with the Open XML SDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the file extension to zip and try again.

Comment: I have a related problem. I have generated an Open XML document using Ruby on Rails. I am able to open the generated XML in notepad and view the XML which looks all good. But I am not able to open it in Excel software. Would you be able to help me with this please? I have posted the issue in detail here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56038034/how-to-save-and-open-an-open-xml-document-as-excel-file Pls help!

Comment: If you could ignore the Ruby on Rails aspect and just give some pointers as to how to save an Open XML document as Excel, that'd be VERY helpful starter! Currently I have no clue what am missing.