# How to save (and open) an Open XML document as Excel file?

Tags: openxml

I have an Open XML document. I would like to know how to save it as an .xlsx file.

I tried opening Excel software and did `Developer -> Import` but that opened my XML file as Excel - but it literally opened the XML file as an XML document and did not open it as an Excel version of an Open XML document.

This is the Open XML document I have:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
    xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
    xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
    xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
    <Worksheet     ss:Name="Forecast">
    <Names>
    <NamedRange     ss:Name="Print_Area"/>
    </Names>
    <Table>
    <Row>
      <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Day1</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="pRange_default"/><NamedCell     ss:Name="Print_Area"/></Cell>
      <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Day2</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="pRange_default"/><NamedCell     ss:Name="Print_Area"/></Cell>
      <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Day3</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="pRange_default"/><NamedCell     ss:Name="Print_Area"/></Cell>
      <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Day4</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="pRange_default"/><NamedCell     ss:Name="Print_Area"/></Cell>
      <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Day5</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="pRange_default"/><NamedCell     ss:Name="Print_Area"/></Cell>

    <Cell/>

      <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">NP25</Data></Cell>
      <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">NP26</Data></Cell>
      <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">NP27</Data></Cell>
      <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">NP28</Data></Cell>
      <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">NP29</Data></Cell>
      <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">NP30</Data></Cell>
    </Row>

    <Row>
        <Cell><Data>1</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="pRange_default"/><NamedCell     ss:Name="Print_Area"/></Cell>
        <Cell><Data>2</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="pRange_default"/><NamedCell     ss:Name="Print_Area"/></Cell>
        <Cell><Data>3</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="pRange_default"/><NamedCell     ss:Name="Print_Area"/></Cell>
        <Cell><Data>4</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="pRange_default"/><NamedCell     ss:Name="Print_Area"/></Cell>
        <Cell><Data>5</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="pRange_default"/><NamedCell     ss:Name="Print_Area"/></Cell>

      <Cell/>

        <Cell><Data>25</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data>26</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data>27</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data>28</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data>29</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data>30</Data></Cell>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Cell><Data>1</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="pRange_default"/><NamedCell     ss:Name="Print_Area"/></Cell>
        <Cell><Data>2</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="pRange_default"/><NamedCell     ss:Name="Print_Area"/></Cell>
        <Cell><Data>3</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="pRange_default"/><NamedCell     ss:Name="Print_Area"/></Cell>
        <Cell><Data>4</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="pRange_default"/><NamedCell     ss:Name="Print_Area"/></Cell>
        <Cell><Data>5</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="pRange_default"/><NamedCell     ss:Name="Print_Area"/></Cell>

      <Cell/>

        <Cell><Data>25</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data>26</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data>27</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data>28</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data>29</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data>30</Data></Cell>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Cell><Data>1</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="pRange_default"/><NamedCell     ss:Name="Print_Area"/></Cell>
        <Cell><Data>2</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="pRange_default"/><NamedCell     ss:Name="Print_Area"/></Cell>
        <Cell><Data>3</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="pRange_default"/><NamedCell     ss:Name="Print_Area"/></Cell>
        <Cell><Data>4</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="pRange_default"/><NamedCell     ss:Name="Print_Area"/></Cell>
        <Cell><Data>5</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="pRange_default"/><NamedCell     ss:Name="Print_Area"/></Cell>

      <Cell/>

        <Cell><Data>25</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data>26</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data>27</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data>28</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data>29</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data>30</Data></Cell>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Cell><Data>1</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="pRange_default"/><NamedCell     ss:Name="Print_Area"/></Cell>
        <Cell><Data>2</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="pRange_default"/><NamedCell     ss:Name="Print_Area"/></Cell>
        <Cell><Data>3</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="pRange_default"/><NamedCell     ss:Name="Print_Area"/></Cell>
        <Cell><Data>4</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="pRange_default"/><NamedCell     ss:Name="Print_Area"/></Cell>
        <Cell><Data>5</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="pRange_default"/><NamedCell     ss:Name="Print_Area"/></Cell>

      <Cell/>

        <Cell><Data>25</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data>26</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data>27</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data>28</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data>29</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data>30</Data></Cell>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Cell><Data>1</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="pRange_default"/><NamedCell     ss:Name="Print_Area"/></Cell>
        <Cell><Data>2</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="pRange_default"/><NamedCell     ss:Name="Print_Area"/></Cell>
        <Cell><Data>3</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="pRange_default"/><NamedCell     ss:Name="Print_Area"/></Cell>
        <Cell><Data>4</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="pRange_default"/><NamedCell     ss:Name="Print_Area"/></Cell>
        <Cell><Data>5</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="pRange_default"/><NamedCell     ss:Name="Print_Area"/></Cell>

      <Cell/>

        <Cell><Data>25</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data>26</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data>27</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data>28</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data>29</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data>30</Data></Cell>
    </Row>
    </Table>
    </Worksheet>
    </Workbook>
```

[image: This is the result of my import]

As you can see Excel import opens my XML file as a literal XML document instead of treating it asn an OpenXML document. please help!

Comment: An excel file is more than just one openXML file. It usually has a bunch of them. Create an excel file -> save it -> rename the extension from .xlsx to .zip -> you can then open and view all the xml files. So if you have a bunch of valid openXML files, you can simply change the extension and open it in Excel

Comment: So with the given OpenXML which I showed above, how can I create an Excel file?

Comment: What you have above is an xml file. I don't know from where you got or generated the above file. My guess would be you need to parse the data from the xml and then generate the excel.

Comment: Download and install [OpenXML SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425). Generate the desired excel you want, open it with this tool and reflect it to obtain equivalent C# code. That should be helpful to get started

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late replay.

To have Excel opening this xml file as an spreadsheet, you need to include the Excel progid in the document attributes.

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?> <!--This is the relevant line-->
    <Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
    xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
    xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
    xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
    <Worksheet     ss:Name="Forecast">
    ..............
```