# Length of cells depending on the length of the string in Excel/CSV

Tags: php, excel, csv

Recently I mastered `fgetcsv` in the hope of writing an array to a file so that I could later open it via Excel, there was no problem with it. Everything turned out ok. But, as far as I understand, there can not be done so to automatically push apart the cells to the length of the string (maybe looked bad)

Now it is written like this:

[image]

I want to know are there are any libraries, so that the cells length is set to the length of the string written to the cell?

It is necessary that it was like this:

[image]

Or maybe there is another approach? For example, manually in Excel to convert all at once so?

I will be grateful for any help, thanks!

Comment: If you want to convert after opening the file then you can select all the columns and use the shortcut Alt+O+C+A.

Comment: @ImranMalek, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV files doesn't have any cell length defintion
They are text files, with Comma Seperated Values (CSV ...)

xlsx files however DO hold such a feature
They are basically xml zipped

You can either look for a php excel library with a function ready or parse the XML yourself...

XML sturcture is reffred to here
[Looking for a clear description of Excel's .xlsx XML format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886027/looking-for-a-clear-description-of-excels-xlsx-xml-format)

Comment: There is more than one... if it holds a function to set column length then this is the one for you...

Answer (score 1):

Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A:D").AutoFit