# Are excel files stored internally as XML files?

Tags: excel, xml, apache-poi, xlsx, sax

I have come to understand that excel files(.xlsx) files are essentially xml file archives internally. I even tried verifying this by extracting the xlsx file in my local.

So if that's the case, how exactly are excel files stored and what is the structure and how do they work.
I also know they can be parsed by SAX parser of Apache POI API.

Please help

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4886027

Comment: @insertusernamehere that post was closed by some reviewer a bit too early I believe. Finally could not really get what I was looking for

Comment: The `Office Open XML` files, so also `*.xlsx` files, are simply `ZIP` archives. You can unzip the `*.xlsx` file to see it's internally structure. See also [Office Open XML file formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML_file_formats).